# Python: how can i replace the header by the first row of a web scraped table

Tags: python, html, excel

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://hkureis.versitech.hku.hk/data.php"
table = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(table)
table.to_excel("Reis.xlsx")
```

How can I get rid of the first row and the first column. Replacing them by the next row and column in python?

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUDxL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with the .to_string(index=False, header=False) method:

```py
print(table.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Result:

[image: result]

Save to Excel (.to_excel()):

```py
table.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: thank you very much it works for the first column,but i actually want to get rid of the first row as well (0-7)

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry, I missed that.
In this case: `print(table.to_string(index=False, header=False))`

Comment: it works, thank you very much! One more question sorry, can i keep the result when i export it to excel file by 'table.to_excel("data.xlsx")'

Comment: @KennyLau could you mark the question as solved? (for other people) 
Thank you ;)

Comment: @KennyLau yes you can. You just have to add the same arguments:
`table.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False, header=False)`